# Update the value in the SQL Server table's column which has special charcters

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a column value in a SQL Server database with this statement:

```
UPDATE t_table 
SET t_table.Notes = '([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(Z|([+\-][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})))' 
WHERE t_table.Name = 'Sample'
```

but it's trowing a DAO issue that the string contains special charterers. So how can this value can be update in table escaping the special characters?

Comment: What is the datatype of Notes?

Comment: it is of nvarchar type

Comment: I tried the same with datatype nvarchar(max), it's working.

Comment: I am getting issue as 
DAO.Database [3075]
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Comment: That error is not SQL Server error, moreover, your syntax is absolutely correct for SQL Server and your command executes successfully. So your problem is in DAO and not in SQL Server. You'd better change the tag of your question

Comment: If we try to add this character it is throwing an error '|'